# Landscape company needs scheduling software

Tags: project-management, scheduling

We need to be able to schedule the following:

1. Regular (weekly, monthly, etc.) service of known duration on some 50
   properties.
2. Longer construction/installation type jobs (several days to weeks)
3. Irregular items.

The ideal software would allow us to create "jobs" with the properties of duration and resource requirement. Then it would allow us to create "Crews" (resources) from various employees.

Finally it would allow us to drag and drop jobs onto the calendar and crews onto various jobs - and monitor for conflicts.

It would also need to be able to indicate which resources are still available for deployment for any given time-frame and which jobs have not been scheduled on a calendar.

Ideally it would permit recurring jobs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Outlook Calendar does all this.

Answer (score 2):

you can try [GenieBelt](http://geniebelt.com) - it has handy Gantt chart, where you can easily schedule all your construction/installation jobs. There is free trial.

Disclosure: I'm from GenieBelt